# using stringtokenizer to count word issue

Tags: java

I have some trouble getting my program to run as it should.  It's about done except for this part i have been working on for a week now and cant get it.  The program should count the number of times each word occurs.

With an input of :

```
This is my file, yes my file My file.. ? ! , : ; / \ |" ^ * + = _( ) { } [ ] < >
```

the output should look like this:

```
    file *3
    is *1
    my *3
    this *1
    yes *1
```

here is my code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class cleanup3 {

public cleanup3() {}

public static void main(String[] args) {   
  try{
     ArrayList myArraylist = new ArrayList();
     System.out.println("Please Enter file");

     InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(System.in) ;

     BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(istream) ;
     String fileName = bufRead.readLine();

     BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

     String s = null;
     while((s = file.readLine()) != null) {                      
         String updated2 = s.replaceAll("[\\.\\,\\?\\!\\:\\;\\/\\|\\\\\\^\\*\\+\\=\\_\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]\\<\\>\"]+"," ");  

         //note to self: missing Single quotes (only if the LAST character of a token)
         StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(updated2.toLowerCase());
         while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
              String nextToken = st.nextToken();

              String myKeyValue = (String)myMap.get(nextToken);
              if(myKeyValue == null){
                  myMap.put(nextToken, "1");
              }
              else{
                  int mycount = Integer.parseInt(myKeyValue) + 1;
                  myMap.put(nextToken, String.valueOf(mycount));
              }
              System.out.println(nextToken);                           
           }   
        }
            System.out.println( updated2.toLowerCase());
            myArraylist.add(updated2.toLowerCase());                     
    }           
    Collections.sort(myArraylist);
    String outPutFileName =  fileName + "sorted.txt";         
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( outPutFileName );
    ps.print(myArraylist.toString());
    ps.flush();
    ps.close();        
  }
  catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println(e.toString());
  }
 }
```

Comment: What does your input file look like?  What does your program do now?

Comment: That replace all has way too many slashes in it. Most of those character don't actually need to be escaped in the character class.

Comment: my input file is       This is my
           file, yes my file

        My file..  ?  ! ,  :  ;  /  \  |" ^  *  +  =  _( )  {  }  [  ]  <  >

Comment: So you want to count occurrences of words?

Comment: before i tried to put the count in, i was able to escape all the char but with no counter

Comment: What constitutes a word, the space between them, or something else? details would be nice,

Comment: Correct James, after/before  it is sorted

Comment: the word it self. when it reads my input file the results should be file *3
        is *1
        my *3
        this *1
        yes *1
after it escape the char

Comment: heres  the last 3 questions i am having trouble with.

Comment: 6.       Each ArrayList entry will have two parts.  The first part is the scrubbed token (word) and the second part is the count of how many times this word appears in the file
for example:  if the token ‘hello’ has been seen 4 times, the ArrayList entry would be: 
                              hello  *4
                      if the token ‘help’ is being newly inserted into the ArrayList, the entry should be:
                              help  *1

Comment: a.       This means that only the first part of each ArrayList entry will be used to determine the sort ordering

b.      When deciding where to insert a new token in the ArrayList, walk the ArrayList from the front until an insert point is reached.  If the same token is found in the ArrayList, don’t insert a new element, just increment the second part.  For example:  if the current token is ‘help’ and ‘help  *5’ is already in the ArrayList, ‘help *5’ should be updated to ‘help *6’

Comment: 7.       After all tokens are read from the original file, a new file should be written with each ArrayList entry on a single line.  The new file should be named:   <Original file name>_sorted.txt

Answer (score 3):

Your code is way too complicated - you only need a few lines of code.

Here's the elegant way to do it:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
for (String word : input.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z ]", "").trim().split(" +"))
    map.put(word, map.containsKey(word) ? map.get(word) + 1 : 1);
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " *" + entry.getValue());
```

The input:

- is folded to lowercase, which takes care of the case issues
- has all non-letters/spaces removed, which takes care of cleaning the input
- is trimmed, which gets the input ready for splitting
- is split on 1-n spaces
- is added to a map which accumulates the totals, employing a ternary to handle initialising the word total

The map entries are then iterated to output the totals.

Using a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) takes care of ordering alphabetically for free.

Answer (score 0):

Try BufferedReader and Regex, like so:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String line;
    try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile))) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
            while ((line = r.readLine())!=null) {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    String word = matcher.group();
                    map.put(word, map.get(word) == null ? 1 : map.get(word)+1);
                }
            }
    }
    System.out.println(map.toString());
```